# Hide Action bar onCreateOptionMenu icon for some activites and fragment android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

A sliding menu was implemented using google navigation drawer with actionbar class.  My problem is onCreateOptionsMenu is being shown in every activities. how can i make onCreateOptionsMenu icon visible and invisible at will. Any idea please.

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
          com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
          inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
          // Handle item selection
          switch (item.getItemId()) {
          case R.id.settings:
              Intent i=new Intent(class1.this, clas2.class);
              startActivity(i);
              return true;
          }
          return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you create menu runtime or have different menu layouts as per your need and in `onCreateOptionsMenu` of your activity set that layout or runtime create those menus or if you want to show no menu icons then just do `menu.clear()`

**Activity A**

```
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
                  com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
                  inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_a, menu);
            }

            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                  // Handle item selection
                  switch (item.getItemId()) {
                  case R.id.settings:
                      Intent i=new Intent(class1.this, clas2.class);
                      startActivity(i);
                      return true;
                  }
                  return false;
            }
```

**Activity B**

```
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
                  menu.clear();
                  com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
                  inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_b, menu);

                  // OR
                  Drawable tmpDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.share_sharingicon);
                    // tmpDrawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGrayFont), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
                  menu.add("ShareMap").setIcon(tmpDrawable).setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
                  menu.add("Directions").setShowAsActionFlags(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
            }

            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                  // Handle item selection
                  switch (item.getItemId()) {
                  case R.id.ShareMap:
                      Intent i=new Intent(class1.this, clas2.class);
                      startActivity(i);
                      return true;
                  case R.id.Directions:
                      Intent i=new Intent(class1.this, clas2.class);
                      startActivity(i);
                      return true;
                  }
                  return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide or show some icon on action bar, you need override method:

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{

```
MenuItem your_icon = menu.findItem(R.id.action_your_icon);


//show icon
your_icon.setvisible(true);
//hide icon
your_icon.setvisible(false);

...
```

}

Besides you need 'supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()' to Invalidate the activity's options menu when action bar items have some change

Comment: by R.id.action_your_icon you mean the onCreateOptionsMenu id

Comment: the icon item id in your action menu

Comment: no i want to hide the onCreateOptionMenu from header

Comment: you mean show nothing on action bar? if so just comment your 'onCreateOptionMenu' I suppose, is that what you want?

Comment: hiding the onCreateOptionMenu icon from header itself for some fragments. i am using sliding menu and for some fragments the onCreateOptionMenu icon is not needed. Need to hide it from action bar title bar

Comment: Ok, your fragments are held by activity, right? so in 'onCreate' of fragment just send back a flag to activity to show or hide some icon, hope this makes sense

Comment: your architecteure analysis is right but already tried this idea not working

Comment: did you use 'supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()' to Invalidate the activity's options menu?

Comment: Hi Dimitri, have you solved the problem? if so please tell the solution, then other persons who have same problem will know the correct solution, thanks!